# Android adapter context

Tags: java, android, adapter

New to Android dev and trying to get Context in my application adapter but I keep getting null exceptions. My attempt it to load the url string into glide, but `glide.with(context)` isn't working. The application pulls values from sqlite (this part works fine), I'm now trying to get one of those values (url) and set it to the imageview via glide. The XML has all the views required.

error: **You cannot start a load on a null Context at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get**

**UsersAdapter.java**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<User> mDataSet;

public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> mDataSet) {
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
}

@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_favorites2, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(v);
    return userViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getName());
    holder.email_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.icon_entry.setText(""+mDataSet.get(position).getName().charAt(0));

    String name = mDataSet.get(position).getName();
    String url = mDataSet.get(position).getEmail();

    // load image into imageview using glide
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_blank)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_blank)
            .into(holder.ivFavorites);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView name_entry, email_entry, icon_entry;
    ImageView ivFavorites;

    UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_layout);
        name_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
        email_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_entry);
        icon_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_entry);
        ivFavorites = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFavorites);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

Reading about adapters and Context I tried the following but with minimal success.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<User> mDataSet;
private Context context;
public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> mDataSet) {
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
}
public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> mDataSet, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

My **Favorites.java** activity which pulls the values from sqlite and displays them in cardview (this also works fine, although I can't get glide to load the image):

public class Favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private UsersAdapter adapter;
private DBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    dbHandler = new DBHandler(Favorites.this);

    Log.d("Reading: ", "reading contacts..");
    ArrayList<User> users = dbHandler.getAllUsers();
    adapter = new UsersAdapter(users);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: The GridLayoutManager uses a Context. So does the DatabaseHandler. Specifically `this`, which is the Activity. You can copy the same pattern into your Adapter constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your context when initializing your adapter

```
adapter = new UsersAdapter(users,getApplicationContext());
```

and in your adapter, implement the equivalent constructor

```
public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> mDataSet, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
}
```

Comment: That helps and clarifies why my Favorites activity would crash, I wasn't passing the content properly.

Thank you.

Comment: @user3591436 no problem, you can check my answer :D